# How to address the characters of a multi dimensional string VECTOR in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, vector

```
vector< vector<string> > att_nam(n, vector<string>(n));
```

*I am creating a 2 dimensional vector of string class, but how do i access the last character of this vector?*
**att_nam[1][2] will access the last string, 
but will**

```
 att_nam[1][2][strlen(att_nam[1][2]);
```

**result in the last character?**

Comment: why are you using `strlen` when `std::string` has a `.length()` method!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
att_nam[i][j][att_nam[i][j].length()-1];
```

That's how to get the last character of the desired string. You were missing some brackets in your code. Also, strlen() is a function that requires a const char* not a string variable so you should use .length() instead.

Comment: oh thats all is the difference? Thank you

Comment: @ReGo There's a shortcut for the last character, `att_nam[i][j].back()`